# Intuitive understanding of 90° scattering

Tags: forces, kinematics, coulombs-law

It can be shown that an electron of velocity $v$ colliding with an ion of charge $Ze$ will be scattered through 90° if its kinetic energy is equal to half the potential energy at a distance equal to the impact parameter in the Coulomb field. I can understand this from a simple quantitative calculation, but am failing to grasp qualitatively why it should be exactly half the potential energy. This situation corresponds to total momentum loss (as the incoming particle is deflected in the perpendicular direction), but intuitively, why does this situation arise if the kinetic energy is half the potential energy at a distance equal to the impact parameter as opposed to any other kinetic energy?

Comment: The momentum is conserved though, it has merely changed direction (and if the central charge recoils some of it goes i to the recoil). As there is always total momentum conservation

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "intuitively". With a little algebra that one can do in one's head, I can provide a pretty simple explanation of why a 90˚ scattering corresponds to half the energy being potential energy at closest impact. Is that intuitive enough, or were you looking for something like a diagram where the answer is immediately obvious?

Comment: @SamuelWeir Could you perhaps expand on this and provide the explanation? A proof such as [this (answer is (3.15)](http://silas.psfc.mit.edu/introplasma/chap3.html#tth_sEc3.1) is the simplest derivation I can find, but if you have anything even simpler, please do share.

Comment: @Mathews24 - The explanation that I was thinking of was a bit more simplified than described in the notes that you just posted. I was thinking of an explanation just in terms of conservation of energy and momentum without going into the details of the particle-to-particle interaction. Can't fit it easily into a comment, so I'll post an answer of it.

Comment: @Mathews24 - Wait a minute. I just realized that there is an issue that needs to be cleared up here. You wrote "... why does this situation arise if the kinetic energy is half the potential energy the 90° scattering angle..", but the $b_{90}$ distance doesn't actually correspond to the distance of closest approach, right? In Figure 3.1 of your notes, it's apparent that the particle would only achieve the $b_{90}$ distance from the nucleus if it weren't deflected. The actual minimum distance (and the PE extremum) corresponds to a distance greater than $b_{90}$, as shown in Fig. 3.1.

Comment: @SamuelWeir The impact parameter is defined as the perpendicular distance between the path of a projectile and the center of a potential field created by an object that the projectile is approaching. I will try to clarify that in my response, but in any case, I am still unaware intuitively of why this deflection is 90° if K = U/2 from a qualitative standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there should exist any intuitive explanation. The statement (which I did not check) is probably correct only for the Coulomb potential, so the specific factor is probably accidental.